# React Component for Chrome Extension not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome Extension using React. Right now I am trying to put my react component into the popup for the extension. It renders fine on a plain webpage (localhost:3000), however when I add my index.html as the default_popup in my manifest.json, only a very small white box pops up. I saw [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53301805/react-chrome-extension-not-rendering) that said this is a Content Security Policy and that locating the SHA256 in the error would fix it. However, I have not found any errors in my console. Please help. I have not really changed the code from the basic react-app, here are my manifest.json and App.js files

```html
<div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Price on stockX: <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
```

```html
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "q React App Sample",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "stockUp"
  },
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Comment: You need to build the code first, see tutorials on using React in chrome extension popup.

Comment: Also, the popup has its own devtools console: right-click inside that popup, then click "inspect".

Comment: Could you possible elaborate on build the code? And I already checked the popup's devtools and it is also blank with no message in the console. Thank you for the speedy response!

Comment: You can use [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=tutorial+react+in+extension+popup) to find the tutorials.

Comment: I looked at these tutorials and I am still having issues. It seems as though they are simply downloading the basic react app that react provides and modifying the manifest.json slightly, and I am following exactly. But I still run into the same issues.

Comment: Did you execute `npm run build`?

Comment: Could can get some context from [here](https://medium.com/oyotech/building-chrome-extension-with-reactjs-beginners-guide-ca44acdf9ffc) about how to build extension and upload on chrome for testing

Answer (score 0):

You must first build the code and then insert it into an extension.

- npm run build
- cross-check manifest.json file and icons
- goto chrome extension
- goto load unpacked option
- load build folder
  It works