# Chrome Extension fails to display UI

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create my first chrome extension using this guide - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/

But for some reason what gets displayed when I click my extension icon in my toolbar is [is the html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYvIX.png) and not the button itself.

This is what my extension directory looks like: [picture of directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fptrp.png)

This is what popup.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=“button.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="changeColor"></button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is what the referenced button.css is:

```
button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  outline: none;
  margin: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

button.current {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white,
              0 0 0 4px black;
}
```

I'd appreciate some help in enabling me to display the correct button instead of the html script for it

Comment: What text editor did you use to create the `popup.html` file?

Comment: Typo: wrong opening quote mark in `href=“button.css"`. Use a standard one `"` .

Answer (score -1):

This most likely is a Content Security Policy error. 
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53301805/react-chrome-extension-not-rendering) for further info and a possible solution.

If this does not solve your issue please provide the other files of your extension so I can take a look at it myself (:

Hope this helped have a great day.